# How to disable a scenario in jbehave?

Tags: scala, gradle, bdd, jbehave

I am adding meta tag:
Meta: skip true
in the story file after the scenario.
Similarly before the runner I am using @UsingEmbedder(metaFilters = Array("+skip")).
This particular scenario should be skipped according to my understanding.

### .story File

```
Scenario: xyz   
Meta: skip    
Given ...
```

### .scala file

```
@UsingEmbedder(metaFilters = Array("-skip"))    
class foo {
}
```

I am new to jbehave. So apology in advance if I am not able to form my question properly.

Comment: so is the problem that your scenario is not skipped, or? You could provide the actual details on how you've configured the embedder. This is tagged both java and scala, which is it?

Comment: Yes, the scenario is not skipped. it's scala. Sorry for the wrong tag.